# How to adjust Icons Margin in the Action bar items in abs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a action bar, which displays the application title on the left side, search action menu item and list/more menu item.

Now, my issues is the margin between the action menu item is not equally divided. So i want to adjust it to equal space between the each other action menu item in actionbar. How i can adjust this action menu item spaces by styling or any other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean, post a screenshot explaining the issue if I'm wrong, but if you are refering to the space between the icons in the ActionBar, they should be equal. Check your icon images, it could be that the images have some different empty space in the borders or that they are not centered. If that was the issue, I recommend you to use this to generate your ActionBar icons:

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=example&theme=dark